# Firebase Realtime Database Retrieved Single Data on Xamarin Android

Tags: c#, firebase-realtime-database, xamarin.android

I successfully get the data from realtime database firebase when I put break point on OndataChange but when I put the break point after the OnDataChange method the records are now null.

```
public void OnDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
{
   
    if (dataSnapshot.Value != null)
    {
        reclist.Clear();
        TempDB rec = new TempDB();


        rec.ID = dataSnapshot.Key;
        rec.Firstname = dataSnapshot.Child("FirstName").Value.ToString();
        rec.Lastname = dataSnapshot.Child("LastName").Value.ToString();
        rec.Address = dataSnapshot.Child("Address").Value.ToString();
        rec.ContactNo = dataSnapshot.Child("Contact number").Value.ToString();
        rec.Email = dataSnapshot.Child("EmailAddress").Value.ToString();
        rec.Password = dataSnapshot.Child("Password").Value.ToString();

        idd = rec.ID;
        Console.WriteLine(id.ToString());
        reclist.Add(rec);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because data is loaded from Firebase asynchronously, while the rest of your code continues. Then once the data is loaded, your `onDataChange` is called with it. This means that the code just after what you shared indeed runs before the code inside the `onDataChange`, and that is working as intended.

The solution is always the same: any code that needs the data from the database needs to be inside `onDataChange`, be called from there, or be otherwise synchronized.

Have a look at these two (Android) examples for some ideas:

- [getContactsFromFirebase() method return an empty list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50434836/getcontactsfromfirebase-method-return-an-empty-list/50435519#50435519)
- [Setting Singleton property value in Firebase Listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33203379/setting-singleton-property-value-in-firebase-listener)

Comment: Thank you so much. I getting the logic now. But why I cant do this inside of ondatachange? id.Text = recList[0].ID;    its says not an instance of an object.

Comment: I'm not sure why that is, but I recommend checking in the debugger (as one of the objects seems to not have been initialized) and search for the error message.

Comment: Can I call the textview Id in onDataChange()?

Comment: Yes, you can. But in your code it seems `id` is not initialized. I recommend learning how to troubleshoot by looking at the [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it) post that was linked to [your follow-up question you deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70283509/please-help-im-getting-an-error-in-id-text-why-im-getting-a-null-id-is-there-a).